# CString to *const *const c_char

Tags: c, rust, ffi

I'm calling some FFI functions in rust code. I'm having some problems with it and I believe it is because I am making a mistake when casting my `CString` to a `*const *const c_char`.

The function signature is something like this,

```rust
foo(strings: *const *const c_char, num_of_strings: i32)
```

In C I would do something like this,

```c
char *str = "...";
foo(&str, 1);
```

In Rust the best I can come up with is

```rust
let str = CString::new(std::fs::read_to_string("path/to/file"));
foo(&str.as_ptr() as *const *const c_char, 1);
```

This complies without problem, but I can't figure out a way to verify that `&str.as_ptr()` is taking the address of the null terminated string. I've tried looking on Stack Overflow and in the Nomicon, but couldn't find anything to check.

It's possible that I am casting correctly and the problem is something else, but I think I'm upholding all the invariants of CStrings, and the file I'm reading into a CString is copy an pasted so it should be totally fine. Either way, I can't be sure I'm casting correctly and I would really like to know the right way. Additionally, if there is a place where this kind of thing is expanded on more, I would love a suggestion for that.

Comment: What is the problem you're getting? From a quick glance, that looks correct.

Comment: @vallentin, Im calling OpenGL's `glShaderSource()` function through the gl crate. My shaders are not compiling correctly. However I have a refrence OpenGL program I use for getting started, and I'm practically copying it line for line. And I litterally did copy the shader, so I didn't think that was the problem. Rather what I've been having trouble with and getting wrong frequently were some of the pointer casts. I couldn't find anything online that delineated how to take a pointer to a pointer in rust to check with. Perhaps I should edit the question to  "Is this the right way to cast ..." ?

Comment: From the signature it looks like that foreign function wants to allocate buffer and put it into provided variable. Can you try to run such code?  `let mut ptr: *mut c_char = ptr::null(); foo(&mut ptr as *mut _);` If result changes, it marks that callee allocates.

Comment: Could you share your OpenGL code for compiling shaders. I have working code for compiling shaders. But I really don't want to answer the question with OpenGL code, when the question doesn't mention it nor suggest that being the issue

Comment: @vallentin I had a problem with my error reporting code, and it was reporting that I had an error after loading shader source, but it was actually in a different spot much earlier in my code.  I did genuinely have no idea whether I was casting it correctly or not though, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: @DavidSullivan Good thing you got it fixed :) if you find `&src.as_ptr() as *const *const c_char` hard to read, then you can also write it like `[src.as_ptr() as *const c_char].as_ptr()` or even shorter like this `[src.as_ptr() as *const _].as_ptr()`. While already answered, you also don't need to use `CString` if you instead pass the length. Personally, my `with_source()` method takes `S: AsRef<str>`.

Answer (score 0):

I read [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glShaderSource.xhtml) of the function you call. It says:

> Specifies an array of pointers to strings containing the source code to be loaded into the shader.

So you should call it like this:

```rust
use std::os::raw::*;
use std::convert::TryInto;

// Docs says it is not necessary to string to be null terminated
// so don't need to use CString
let shader_code = std::fs::read_to_string("path/to/file").unwrap();
assert!(shader_code.is_ascii()); // I don't know if OpenGL supports utf8
let codes_array: [*const c_char; 1] = [shader_code.as_ptr() as _];
let codes_lengths: [c_int; 1] = [shader_code.len().try_into().unwrap()];

// I do not know exact api of your Rust wrapper
glShaderSource(
     shader_handle,
     codes_array.len().try_into().unwrap(),
     codes_array.as_ptr(),
     codes_lengths.as_ptr()
);
```

I replaced using of CString by just String because docs says that it is not necessary to string to be null terminated if lengths are provided.

> If length is NULL, each string is assumed to be null terminated. If length is a value other than NULL, it points to an array containing a string length for each of the corresponding elements of string. Each element in the length array may contain the length of the corresponding string (the null character is not counted as part of the string length) or a value less than 0 to indicate that the string is null terminated. The source code strings are not scanned or parsed at this time; they are simply copied into the specified shader object.

Comment: Ignoring `glShaderSource`, did you try to compile the first 3 lines? Because you have multiple issues. (1) The `Result` returned by `CString::new` and `read_to_string` is not handled. (2) You're missing a cast to `*const c_char`. (3) `CString` does not have a `len` method. (4) You cannot use `_` like that.

Comment: @vallentin Ok, made changes to make code compile. Also removed CString usage because it is likely to be unnessary.

Comment: It's a good thing you quoted the docs. Because the strings **must** be null terminated, if `length` is null.